# When would you use "всё в порядке"?

Tags: перевод

I am curious when it is approprite to use the expression: "всё в порядке" ?

Could I use it if someone ask me: "как дела"? or could I use the expression in other situations like if someone asks me how the progress is in a projekt (work related issues)?

Do you use this sentence and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question (about status in some specific area):
— Как (у тебя) дела в школе / на работе/ на личном фронте/ с проектом ХХ?
Answer:
— Все в порядке.

Question (general):
— Как (у тебя) дела?
Answers:

- *very good:*
  — Хорошо! / Замечательно!/ Отлично! / В шоколаде (*colloquial*)
- *OK*:
  — Хорошо. / Нормально.
- *not good:*
  — Хорошо… /  Как сажа бела́ (*colloquial*)
- *joke instead of answer:*
  —  Как у зебры. / Не дождетесь! / Пока не родила́ *(only female, not necessary pregnant)*

Comment: And not only female ;)

Answer (score 0):

The answer "***всё в порядке***" is usually given in response to an inquiry about the status of things (project, activity, whatnot), especially if the question is expressed with some concern about the success.

In response to "*как дела?*" one would usually say "*спасибо, ничего*" or any variation of "*хорошо*", for example, "*замечательно*" or even "*лучше всех*".  That is, unless one really wants to share the troubles and talk about a possible solution to them.

Comment: `response to an inquiry about the status of things` - also quite often it precisely stands for such an inquiry: "Всё в порядке?"

Answer (score 0):

*"Всё в порядке?"* usually asks when you think something wrong with another human.

*(meet a man lying on the ground)* *Всё в порядке? Может, вызвать скорую?* (Are you all right? Maybe call an ambulance?)